# Outlook 365: Manually update to a specific version

Tags: outlook, office365

I have Outlook 365 and I would like to update it manually to a specific version to check the installation of an add-in for a specific Outlook version.

Is there any place where I can download it and then install it manually? Is it possible?

I need to install manually Outlook update to version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20198 for x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, installations of Microsoft Office are configured to automatically update your Office installation when new updates are made publicly available. Occasionally, you may have to revert to an earlier version or build of an Office installation. The same applies to updates to specific Office versions as well.

You can use the `Office Deployment Tool` for that. So, download and run the self-extracting executable file from the following [Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=49117) link. This file contains the Office Deployment Tool executable (Setup.exe) and a sample configuration file (Configuration.xml):

```
<Configuration>
<Updates Enabled="TRUE" TargetVersion="16.0.xxxxx.yyyyy" />
</Configuration>
```

In the configuration XML, `16.0.xxxxx.yyyyy` represents the full version number that you need to update your Office.

Open an elevated Command Prompt window. To do this, click `Start`, type `cmd` in the Start Search box, right-click `cmd.exe`, and then click `Run as administrator`. Switch to the file location for the `Setup.exe` and `Config.xml` files. Run the following command:

```
setup.exe /configure config.xml
```

Start any Office application (such as Excel), and then select `File` > `Account`.

In the `Product Information` section, select `Update Options` > `Update Now`. Viola!

Finally, you may find the [Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7) and [How to revert to an earlier version of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841) helpful.